# Retreive data and time from a datetime string

Tags: python, date, datetime, date-parsing

In my project I have a string like this one:

> "2018-03-07 06:46:02.737951"

I would like to get two variables: one in date format that contains the data, and the other for the time.

I tried:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('2018-03-07 06:46:02.737951', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```

but I get an error.

Then I tried:

```
from dateutil import parser
dt = parser.parse("2018-03-07 06:46:02.737951")
```

but I don't know what I can do with these results.

How can I extract the values for my vars "date_var" and "time_var"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match your string exactly. Reference: [strftime-and-strptime-behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.strptime('2018-03-07 06:46:02.737951', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

print(dt.date())
print(dt.time())


d = dt.date() # extract date
t = dt.time() # extract time

print(type(d)) # printout the types
print(type(t))
```

Output:

```
2018-03-07
06:46:02.737951

<class 'datetime.date'>
<class 'datetime.time'>
```

Your format string is something along the lines of:

```
Month as locale’s abbreviated name.  
Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
Year with century as a decimal number.
Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM.
```

with some spaces and `:` in it - which does not match your format.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Accessing the time as an object:
the_time = dt.time()
#the_time
datetime.time(23, 55)

# Accessing the time as a string:
the_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
'23:55:00'
```

Similar for Date

Refer [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)